# React - textDecoration:'none' not removing underline in link

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, frontend

So I'm trying to remove the underline from my link using textDecoration:'none' , but for some reason the link doesn't disappear,even after using !important. Anyone know what it may be? I'm pretty noob so it must be something simple hehe.
Cheers!

```
index.tsx:

<div className={classes.register}><div className={classes.conta}>Não possui uma conta? <a href='#'> Cadastre-se</a></div></div>


style.jss.ts:

register: {
    position: 'relative',
    width:'100%',
    height:'50px',
    borderRadius:'10px',
    backgroundColor: '#f1f5fb',
    border: 'solid 1px #e6eaee',
    paddingTop:'15px'
  },

  a:{
    textDecoration:'none'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should apply your "a" class to your a component.

```
<a href='#' className={classes.a}> Cadastre-se</a>
```